# Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File doesn't work in Cron Job Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab, magento-cron, cronjobs

Does any one know why `$this->driverFile->isExists('pub/media/')` doesn't work in Cron Job ?

I've a Cron Job look like this:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Cron;

use Namespace\Module\Helper\Data;

class Scan
{
    public function __construct(
        Data $helperData,
    ) {
        $this->helperData = $helperData;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->helperData->scanFiles();
        // do something
    }
}
```

and a Helper call to `$this->driverFile->isExists('pub/media/')` but it return `false` when `pub/media/` is actually exists and run manual by Controller still return `true` (i mean only Cron Job have this issue):

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File as DriverFile;

class Helper extends AbstractHelper 
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        DriverFile $driverFile
    ) {
        $this->driverFile = $driverFile;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function scanFiles() {
        $directory = 'pub/media';
        if ($this->checkIfFileExists($directory)) {
            $files = $this->driverFile->readDirectoryRecursively($directory);
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $fileSize = $this->driverFile->stat($file)['size'];
                // do something
            }
        }
    }

    public checkIfFileExists($directory) {
        return $this->driverFile->isExists($directory) && $this->driverFile->isReadable($directory);
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging with my team, i've found that cron doesn't run from root directory, so `$this->driverFile->isExists('pub/media/')` should be `$this->driverFile->isExists(YOUR_DIRECTORY_DIR . 'pub/media/')`

Example: `$this->driverFile->isExists('/var/www/html/Magento233/pub/media/')`
So i've copy the content of `Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File` to my helper and make it look like this:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Glob;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Class FileCron
 * copy from Magento233/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php
 * but add (BP . '/') in directory path, so that will not causing issue with check file in cron job
 * @package Jajuma\ImageOptimizerUltimate\Helper
 */
class FileCron extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $scheme = '';

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Returns last warning message string
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getWarningMessage()
    {
        $warning = error_get_last();
        if ($warning && $warning['type'] == E_WARNING) {
            return 'Warning!' . $warning['message'];
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Is file or directory exist in file system
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return bool
     * @throws FileSystemException
     */
    public function isExists($path)
    {
        clearstatcache();
        $result = @file_exists(BP . '/' . $this->getScheme() . $path);
        if ($result === null) {
            throw new FileSystemException(
                new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('An error occurred during "%1" execution.', [$this->getWarningMessage()])
            );
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Gathers the statistics of the given path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return array
     * @throws FileSystemException
     */
    public function stat($path)
    {
        clearstatcache();
        $result = @stat($this->getScheme() . $path);
        if (!$result) {
            throw new FileSystemException(
                new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('Cannot gather stats! %1', [$this->getWarningMessage()])
            );
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Check permissions for reading file or directory
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return bool
     * @throws FileSystemException
     */
    public function isReadable($path)
    {
        clearstatcache();
        $result = @is_readable(BP . '/' . $this->getScheme() . $path);
        if ($result === null) {
            throw new FileSystemException(
                new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('An error occurred during "%1" execution.', [$this->getWarningMessage()])
            );
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Read directory recursively
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return string[]
     * @throws FileSystemException
     */
    public function readDirectoryRecursively($path = null)
    {
        $result = [];
        $flags = \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS | \FilesystemIterator::UNIX_PATHS;
        try {
            $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator(BP . '/' . $path, $flags),
                \RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
            );
            /** @var \FilesystemIterator $file */
            foreach ($iterator as $file) {
                $result[] = $file->getPathname();
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new FileSystemException(new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($e->getMessage()), $e);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Return path with scheme
     *
     * @param null|string $scheme
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getScheme($scheme = null)
    {
        return $scheme ? $scheme . '://' : '';
    }
}
```

As you can see, I added `BP . '/' .` before `$this->getScheme() . $path` so it look like: `@file_exists(BP . '/' . $this->getScheme() . $path)`.

Why is `BP`? It's because `BP` is `YOUR_DIRECTORY_DIR` which supported by PHP.

You can read about BP [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176920/70258).

After create helper, you can call it to replace the old function `isExists()` of original file.

Answer (score 0):

Check PHP Version:
Ensure that you are using a version of PHP that supports symlink() function. This function requires PHP 5.3.0 or later.

Enable symlink() Function:
Open your PHP configuration file (php.ini), and make sure that the symlink() function is not disabled. Look for the disable_functions directive and ensure that symlink is not listed. If it is listed, remove it and restart your web server.