# Magento 2 Import image by CSV to custom table using script

Tags: image-upload, magento2.4.3, file-upload

I have custom table with some fields including the image.

Now I want to import the data from CSV to custom table with the image.

Fields are like first_name, last_name, image.

I have done import for the text fields but need some idea regarding image upload.

In the image column I will pass the name of image. When import I need to import the image to the specific folder from given path on the site.

For example, I will upload images by FTP to pub/media/upload_images add the image name in the CSV when I import CSV it will take image from pub/media/upload_images and upload to employee_images folder.

```
$employeeData = [];
$tableName = $connection->getTableName('employee_data');

foreach ($csvData as $rowData) {
    $employeeData[] = [
                "first_name" => $rowData['first_name'],
                "last_name" => $rowData['last_name'],
                "image" => $rowData['image']
            ];
}
if (count($employeeData)) {
            $connection->insertMultiple($tableName, $employeeData);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> **You can use the below code after insert records. To move an image from one location to another location**

```
protected $backendFile

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $backendFile
) {
    $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
}

$result = $this->mediaDirectory->copyFile($SourcePath,$DestinationPath);
```

You can get file path by using this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176917/82670